# How to get the global css background-color at a specific position using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking to get the background color of the viewable page at a specific position.

I want to get the bg color of the page at 70px from the top of the page view, this is because my header/navbar's height is 70px and that's where where I want to get the color of every element that scrolls past that point.

This currently gets the relative position of the container which holds every element that I want to get the color of ***at*** that point... (what I mean by, "***at that point***", is that the bg-color may be a gradient)

```js
$(window).on("scroll", () => {

    let selector = $(".selector")

    // get pixel color at pos y = 70px, pos x does not matter
    let content   = $(".container")
    let rect      = content.get(0).getBoundingClientRect()

    // the navbar is fixed, therefore, the containers relative top pos is 0... so we add 70
    let position  = rect.top + 70
    console.log(position)
})
```

My end goal is to dynamically change the bg-color of the selector element to whatever color from any element that passes the absolute pos of y=70.

As you can see, I'm currently getting the relative y position from the container element.

There are 2 ways that I think could work, yet unsure how to proceed...

1. Get the pixel color at the absolute pos of y=70
2. Or the way I've already attempted, which is to get the color at the relative y pos of the container

*Please ask for more info if something is not clear, I am aware that this is an irregular task I'm trying to achieve.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not believe there is a way to '*get the pixel color at the absolute pos of y=70*' So you would have to examine what element is viewable at that position of the Window. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is absolutely doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Example using `html2canvas` and `canvas.getImageData`

I created an example using `html2canvas` library. This library will generate an image of the website and store it in a canvas (this canvas we get in a variable and is not visible on the site). With `canvas.getImageData` you can get the color on the image of a certain pixel at a certain offset.

### Update nov 14; performance improvement

I have updated the script so there is only one print screen loaded on page load. Also when a rbg color is obtained, it is stored in a global array to improve performance, the next time it is loaded from the array.

### Example

See a working example at https://833964.playcode.io/

### Explanation

The function below renders an image using `html2canvas`, a printscreen of the website.  After the image is loaded by `html2canvas` we can obtain the color of a certain pixel at a certain offset.

### Code

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<div style="width: 100%; position: fixed; background-color: #000;height: 69px;">
    <h1 style="color: #fff; width: 500px; float:left;">Color box (on the right)</h1>
    <span style="width: 30px; height: 30px; float:right" id="colorDisplay"></span>
</div>

<div style="height:550px; background-color:#00ff00;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:550px; background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:550px; background-color:#0f0f0f;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:1050px; background-color:#ff0000;width:100%"></div>

<script>
window.canvas = null;
window.canvasContext = null;
window.rgb = [];

function debounce(func, timeout)
{
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

function setColor(offsetY)
{
    var p = null;
    if(window.canvas == null) {
            //... nothing
    } else {
        if(window.canvasContext == null){
      window.canvasContext = window.canvas.getContext('2d');
        }
        if(window.rgb[offsetY] !== undefined) {
            p = window.rgb[offsetY];
        } else {
            p = window.canvasContext.getImageData(1, 70 + offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            window.rgb[offsetY] = p;
        }
        document.getElementById("colorDisplay").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + p[0]+", "+p[1]+", "+p[2] + ")";
    }
}

function loadCanvas()
{
    html2canvas(document.body, {scale: '1', scrollY: 0}).then((canvas) => {
        window.canvas = canvas;
        setColor(window.pageYOffset);
    });
}

(function(){
    loadCanvas();
    window.onscroll = debounce(() => setColor(window.pageYOffset), 10);
})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Note

If a window resize changes the layout of your website, so that colors don't match anymore, you can consider reloading the canvas. You can do this with this script:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    window.canvas = null;
    window.canvasContext = null;
    window.rgb = [];
    loadCanvas();
}, true);
```

Comment: That's an almost perfect example of what I want to achieve,  however, there is a delay from when I stop scrolling before it changes the color, which is not ideal for me. any way to make is almost instant?

Comment: yes, there is a debounce function at the bottom `window.onscroll = debounce(() => setColor(window.pageYOffset), 500);`, change the 500 (half a second) to a lower value.

Comment: i would set it to 10 for example

Comment: I'm having trouble with this implementation when switching monitors, it gives unpredictable results. I will look into it.

Comment: I have updated the script, I needed to add `{scale: '1'}` in the call `html2canvas(screenshotTarget, {scale: '1'}).then(....`. Should be working fine now.

Comment: alright thanks for the clarification, I'll look into it and I'll send an update with my results!

Comment: My browser on my mobile phone crashed so I updated the script. It only takes one screenshot at page load. It also caches the rgb color based on y coordination, so next time you scroll to that point, it is loaded from cache. So performance is improved now.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me! It works perfectly as I needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are targeting your problem the wrong way. If your end goal is to dynamically change the bg-color of the selector element to whatever color from any element that passes the absolute pos of y=70, I would suggest you write a function that constantly checks the position of every element on your page and if it passes the absolute position of y=70 get the background color and set it to the selector. If this method is conveinent for you but don't know how to apply it comment below and I will help with it.

Comment: I do believe I could figure out how to apply that, but what if an element has a background gradient, then I'll want to set the bg of the selector element to each color as it gradually passes though the gradient?

Comment: do you mean setting a select color from the gradient (for example if the gradient consists of red and green colors and passes through pos 70 you want to set the element green then red) or apply the whole gragient to the element as it is (i.e applying both red and green together on the element)

Comment: yes, "do you mean setting a select color from the gradient (for example if the gradient consists of red and green colors and passes through pos 70 you want to set the element green then red)"

Comment: that is a little complicated. What I would suggest is reverse engineering this : http://jsfiddle.net/vksn3yLL/

Comment: see the slider position deterimines the color of the element so to apply this with color gradients. First get the color gradient convert it to hex or rgba ... then set it to the element with respect to the elements position

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function setBackground(color) {
    $(".page").css("backgroundColor", color);
  }

  function isAtTop(elem, pos) {
    var top = $(elem).offset().top;
    var bottom = top + $(elem).height();
    console.log(top, bottom, pos)
    return (top <= (pos + 70) && bottom >= (pos + 70));
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var self = $(this);
    $(".content .item").each(function() {
      if (isAtTop(this, self.scrollTop())) {
        setBackground($(this).css("background-color"));
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.item {
  width: 340px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item red">
      Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item orange">
      Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item yellow">
      Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="item green">
      Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="item blue">
      Item 5
    </div>
    <div class="item purple">
      Item 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `.scrollTop()` we can determine how far down the page the User has Scrolled. We then can examine the elements and change the background.

Comment: I think it is a nice example. But, this is unclear in the question (have a look at some of the comments), he wants to get the color at offset 70 y of a gradient.

Comment: @Douma I see the comments. OP did not provide an example of the HTML, so when I created this answer and example, it was before those comments.